# NoClassDefFoundError org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$35

Tags: java, spring, classloader, noclassdeffounderror, timertask

Please have a look and provide advice. 
I'm totally lost with that exception.
It happens inside of spring-orm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar and it looks like some classloading issue.
I do have **spring-orm-4.0.6**.RELEASE.jar in my WEB-INF\lib, and I do have **hibernate-core-4.3.6**.Final.jar there, 
and I'm trying to run this app under Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 (yes, pretty old, as the project I'm trying to refresh)
I can not understand why classloader able to load HibernateTemplate, but unable to load HibernateTemplate$35, they are sitting in the same dir in the same jar...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$35
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1011)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1003)
        at xxx.xxx.SelectionDAO.list(SelectionDAO.java:142)
```

the code which call hibernate:

```
  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
  public <Entity> List<Entity> list(final Class<Entity> entityClass) {
      DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(entityClass);
      return (List)getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
  }
```

just to clarify, I use org.springframework.orm.**hibernate4**.HibernateTemplate

Maybe this also make sence, but I found out this code is invoked from

```
private void startSessionClean() {
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                  dao.list(UserSessions.class);
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();        
                log.error("Error in session cleaner", throwable);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, DELAY, DELAY);
}
```

So I am guessing this might be somehow linked with different Thread classloader? Any ideas?

Comment: do you use maven or just copied the jars in WEB-INF?

Comment: `Spring 3.1` comes with support for both `hibernate 3` and `hibernate 4`. But `HibernateTemplate` is part of hibernate3 package in `Spring 3`.
If you want to use `HibernateTemplate` you should use `Hibernate 3`. If you want to use `Hibernate4` then `hibernateTemplate` cannot be used.

Comment: I use maven, but to be honest I'm not very familiar with it. could I check something I miss there?

Comment: ankur-singhal, could you clarify your point?
I use HibernateTemplate from org.springframework.orm.hibernate4, it still there, as you could see in stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed implementation from TimerTask to spring scheduled runnable by TaskScheduler and problem dissapeared

Answer (score 0):

Check out the javadoc of [HibernateTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html), try convert it to the new style `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`

Comment: this direct me toward handling the situation when current session doesn't exists, and impose opening and closing it. but I'm just porting the code (a huge amount of it) and don't want it make any difference if possible

Comment: I use hibernate4 and this jars are in class path, they are in WEB-INF\lib and they are in server\lib folder too (put them there just to check if it helps, but it's not)